# How can I mount a TV to the wall so that it folds away?

Tags: mounting, television

I currently have a projector that I connect to my Mac or to my XBox 360, and then project onto a screen that pulls down over a window.

I now want to get a PS4, but the PS4 only has an HDMI output and my projector has no HDMI input. From what I can gather online, while there are options for converting HDMI output to a VGA or component input (both of which my projector has; it also has S-Video), these are far from perfect solutions and often don't work at all, or work inconsistently.

So, if I want to use a PS4 it seems I have two options: buy a new projector, or buy a TV. It seems that new, HDMI-compatible projectors are expensive, although there are some cheap ones on Amazon. But -- and here's the first part of my question -- are these cheap Amazon projectors any good?

As for the option of buying a TV, this is made more complicated by the fact that I live in a small place and there's no room for a big TV. But is it possible to mount a TV on the ceiling, so that most of the time the screen is flush to the ceiling but when I want to watch TV I can pull the TV down 90 degrees so that is parallel to the walls/window? It would also probably be necessary to be able to adjust the height of the TV when it is pulled down.

It might also be possible to mount the TV on the wall next to the window, so that when the TV is not in use it is perpendicular to the walls/window, and then pulls out when someone wants to use the TV. Going down this route would probably require that it be possible to rotate the TV, to, to make it possible to completely hide the TV away behind a cabinet.

I've found a few TV mounts online that come close to doing what I want, but nothing that does *precisely* what I want. Are there any particular brands of mount I should be looking at? And should I be trying to mount the TV on the ceiling or on the wall?

Comment: What's above/below the area, could the TV go up into the ceiling or down into the floor?

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/ebfde63e-3048-4796-878c-97cede30e7f2/25fef2456158776689200063ee7f7a59

Comment: That's what the area looks like: essentially, wherever the TV goes it will have to fold away somehow so it doesn't block the window

Answer (score 1):

The question might be, where are you thinking to fold it away to? There is no room there. I would certainly try something like this first:

[http://www.amazon.com/Coredy-Graphics-Multiple-Monitors-1920/dp/B0129CP6BO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448758981&sr=8-1&keywords=hdmi+to+vega+adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0129CP6BO)

This would certainly be much cheaper and less hassle.

Start with the easiest cheapest solution and work you way up.

Save yourself lots of time and energy in the process.

Happy Saturday!